# Annotating adjacent values in a list

Tags: python, list

It's supposed to be a roll of dice (random) then adjacent values (runs) are supposed to be in ( ). One challenge is using the current - 1 with the 0 index (think I got that resolved by using range(len(dieRun) -1). But another challenge is using 'current + 1' as it tends to 'out of range' errors.

One thought I have is to maybe build a function to compare the values for adjacents? Then use whatever return I get from that to reference a variable, then use that variable in a formatted Print of the dieRun? But, I don't see how that would be better as then I'd still have to figure out how to place that variable as a "(" or ")" with the print(dieRun) list.
Still a newb.

```
def main():

    from random import randint
    counter = 0
    inRun = 0
    dieRun = []
    while counter < 20:
        roll = randint(0,6)
        dieRun.append(roll)
        counter = counter +1

    index = 0
    counter = 0
    value = 0
    inRun == False
    print(dieRun) # just to see what I'm working with
    while counter < len(dieRun):
        for i in range(0, len(dieRun)-1):

            if dieRun[i] != dieRun[i-1]:
                print(")" , end= "")
                inRun = False
                counter = counter + 1

            if dieRun[i] == dieRun[i+1]:
                inRun = True
                print("(")
                counter = counter + 1

            print(dieRun[i])
        if inRun:
            print("(")
   if inRun :
    print(")", end="")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the output like: 1(3 3) 4 5 (6 6 6) 2 1 3 (2 2) 1 (4 4) 5 6 1 2

```
from random import randint

dieRun = []
for i in range(20):
    roll = randint(0,6)
    dieRun.append(roll)


inRun = False
print(dieRun)

for i, n  in enumerate(dieRun):   
    if i < len(dieRun)-1:
        if not inRun:
            if n == dieRun[i+1]:
                print('(', n,' ', end='')
                inRun = True
            else:
                print(n,' ', end='')
        else:
            if n != dieRun[i+1]:
                print(n, ')',' ', end='')
                inRun = False
            else:
                print(n,' ', end='')
    else:
        if dieRun[i-1] == n:
            print(n, ')')
        else:
            print(n)
```

just a thought, hope it help.

Comment: Thanks. After running this through Python Tutor it totally makes sense. Now I understand the point of the inRun True/False. That's what is directing the flow of the loop. Awesome. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: No problem, glad it helps. If you don't mind, would you please give my posts positive votes. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick fix, I have commented in the code.

For the inline print, you have provided the solution 'print(")" , end= "")', but I don't know why you didn't make it for every print().

```
if dieRun[i] != dieRun[i-1]:  # will check the first number with last number
dieRun[0] != dieRun[-1]:      # [-1] is the last item in the list

if dieRun[i] == dieRun[i+1]:  # will index out of length
dieRun[len(..)-1] != dieRun[len(..)]:      # [len(..)] wil be out of range
```

Since the head and tail of the list will always cause problem, I just chopped them off from the for loop, and do it manually.

There must be some cleaner solution:

```
from random import randint
counter = 0
inRun = 0
dieRun = []
while counter < 20:
    roll = randint(0,6)
    dieRun.append(roll)
    counter = counter +1



index = 0
counter = 0
value = 0
inRun == False
print(dieRun)

# while counter < len(dieRun):   # while loop is redundant with the for loop
print('(', dieRun[0],' ', end='')  # print the first number manually

for i in range(1, len(dieRun)-1):   
    if dieRun[i] != dieRun[i-1]:
        print(")(" , end= "")  # change ")" to ")("
        inRun = False
        counter = counter + 1
    """
    these are redundant, just like if True, don't need elif not True
    # if dieRun[i] == dieRun[i+1]:
    #     inRun == True
    #     print("(", end='')
    #     counter = counter + 1
    """

    print(dieRun[i],' ', end='')

print(dieRun[-1],')', end='')  # print the last number manually
```

Comment: Hey thanks. At least it prints out in a row now. I did some more reading on the end= and have a better grasp of it now.

Your code is better than mine, but there are still a lot of duplicate )'s and ('s. I'm trying to just get () around the adjacents. For example:

1(3 3) 4 5 (6 6 6) 2 1 3 (2 2) 1 (4 4) 5 6 1 2

Thanks a lot for your time and input.